# Lambda captures with initializers and Objective-C++

Tags: c++, c++17, closures, objective-c++

Trying the following code, written into a `.mm` file and compiled with `g++ -std=c++17`

```
int x;
auto a = [c = x]{};
```

It results in the compiler complaining

```
error: 'c' was not declared in this scope
```

Thus it looks to me that lambdas with captures initializers are not supported in Objective-C++.

Experimenting with it I also noticed that the following compiles successfully:

```
int x;
int c;
auto a = [c = x]{};
```

But with a totally different behavior than it would have in pure C++. In fact, it looks like `c` and `x` are both being captured, *and* that `c` is *then* assigned the value of `x`.

As a matter of facts, the [following code exits](https://godbolt.org/z/sEPWGbTWe) with a code of `2`, which proves what stated above.

```
int x = 1;
int c;
auto a = [c = x]{return c+x;};

int main() {
    return a();
}
```

---

Haven't found this documented or even discussed anywhere, surely my fault? Does anybody have any pointer to any form of (un)official documentation on the matter? Is this an issue with the specific implementation, or a language limitation?

Comment: You probably need to specify on the compiler command line which C++ version you're targeting. For `clang`, that's `-std=c++17` for example. In an Xcode target's build settings, you can select that for the "C++ Language Dialect" in the "Apple Clang - Language - C++" section.

Comment: If relying on subtle version-specific features, it might also be worth putting something like `static_assert(__cplusplus >= 201703L, "This file uses C++17 features");` near the top of the compilation unit.

Comment: I have specified the version, it's stated at the very beginning of my post.

Comment: Your first snippet is a valid C++17 code, so it should be related to Objective-C++

Comment: @moia it is related to Objective-C++, in fact. Not sure I get what you mean.

Comment: I did not get the `error: 'c' was not declared in this scope` when doing the first code snippet.  Using Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1).  `clang++ -std=c++17 FabioA.mm`

Comment: I did confirm that `__OBJC__` and `__OBJC2__` were defined (as **1**), as well as `__cplusplus` (**201703L**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Haven't found this documented or even discussed anywhere, surely my fault? Does anybody have any pointer to any form of (un)official documentation on the matter? Is this an issue with the specific implementation, or a language limitation?

There are no any limitations in regards to lambdas in Objective-C++. Essentially Objective-C++ is a superset of C++, and compiler should be able to properly interpret (any) legal C++ code. Every code snippet you provided as well as the following code:

```cpp
int x = 1;
auto a = [c = x]{ return c + x; };

int main()
{
    return a();
}
```

...compile without issues with Apple Clang 14 on MacOS using the following set of flags:

```
% clang -x objective-c++ --std=c++17 Lambda.mm
```

The behavior you are observing is most likely a GCC bug and doesn't require any documentation, it needs to be fixed.

Comment: I actually didn't know that also the variable which part of the initializer is captured. Got an reference to the standard where it says so? 

Opened a bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=109728

Comment: @FabioA. in your last sample the lambda should not capture anything, it declares a new variable `c` in the capture list, assigns its value to `x` and then refers to `x` through the global scope. The global `c` variable [should not change at all](https://godbolt.org/zT69hMb1Yc)